# How can I optimize, improve my android app?

Tags: android, json, optimization, loading

For example I have a server based app, which does JSON parsing, fetches image url and then download image from the server, which is then clickable to a webview. How can I make it take less time in loading the data? My solution for this is that I do Asynch task in the background or trigger a service as soon as the application starts, so that when user wants the data, he gets it immediately. No progress bar needed!

Besides this, what are the other ways that can help me optimize the app for a best user experience? Please suggest, i am a newbie in android.

Comment: How dynamic is the server data? A clear option is adding support for caching/storing the JSON response and support `If-Modified-Since` on the server side to ensure "freshness".

Comment: Is the server-side data something that you can cache on the device?  How does the app function if a network connection is not available?

Comment: Yep, I could cache the data on my device. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for image downloading You can use cache concept that keep image in local cache of device if the image is available in device cache then it will not again download from server 
Or you can use fast image downloading concept provided by Google itself  [Click here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Comment: Thanks, I can cache. But I also wanted what else can I do to make my app better in performance, like consuming less memory on the device. Could that be possible?

Comment: @Feona At the place of service you can use Intent Service.It runs separate from your main thread.this makes your app more responsible and smooth  and It will be stopped automatically when your downloading is done.